# Why is this rowspan not working?

Tags: html, html-table

I have here a basic two row table where the first row's column "A" should span across both rows.   Then, the columns 2,3,4 should appear under headings B,C,D.

What am I overlooking here?

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tbody>
  <tr style="background-color:blue; color:white;">
   <td rowpsan="2">A</td>
   <td>B</td>
   <td>C</td>
   <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color:yellow;">1</td>
   <td style="background-color:yellow;">2</td>
   <td style="background-color:yellow;">3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

typo

```
<td rowpsan="2">A</td>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I've been looking at this for 5 minutes.

Comment: your very welcome

Answer (score 3):

it's a typo in the code: "rowpsan = 2"

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tbody>
  <tr style="background-color:blue; color:white;">
   <td rowspan="2">A</td>
   <td>B</td>
   <td>C</td>
   <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color:yellow;">1</td>
   <td style="background-color:yellow;">2</td>
   <td style="background-color:yellow;">3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```